# Problema con una consulta en sql usando joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
db_schools(
  sch_id serial primary key
);

db_people(
  peo_id serial primary key
);

db_terms(
  ter_id serial primary key,
  sch_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_ter_sch_id foreign key(sch_id) references db_schools(sch_id)
);

db_students(
  stu_id serial primary key,
  peo_id integer not null unique,
  ter_id integer not null,
  stu_status varchar(20) not null default 'IN PROGRESS',
  constraint fk_stu_peo_id foreign key(peo_id) references db_people(peo_id),
  constraint fk_stu_ter_id foreign key(ter_id) references db_terms(ter_id)
);

db_admins(
  adm_id serial primary key,
  peo_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_adm_peo_id foreign key(peo_id) references db_people(peo_id)
);

db_schools_admins(
  sch_adm_id serial primary key,
  sch_id integer not null,
  adm_id integer not null,
  ter_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_sch_adm_sch_id foreign key(sch_id) references db_schools(sch_id),
  constraint fk_sch_adm_adm_id foreign key(adm_id) references db_admins(adm_id),
  constraint fk_sch_adm_ter_id foreign key(ter_id) references db_terms(ter_id),
  constraint unique_schools_admins_fields unique(sch_id, adm_id, ter_id)
);

db_teachers(
  tea_id serial primary key,
  peo_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_tea_peo_id foreign key(peo_id) references db_people(peo_id)
);

db_schools_teachers(
  sch_tea_id serial primary key,
  sch_id integer not null,
  tea_id integer not null,
  ter_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_sch_tea_sch_id foreign key(sch_id) references db_schools(sch_id),
  constraint fk_sch_tea_tea_id foreign key(tea_id) references db_teachers(tea_id),
  constraint fk_sch_tea_ter_id foreign key(ter_id) references db_terms(ter_id),
  constraint unique_schools_teachers_fields unique(sch_id, tea_id, ter_id)
);

db_payments(
  pay_id serial primary key,
  sch_id integer not null,
  ter_id integer not null,
  constraint fk_pay_sch_id foreign key(sch_id) references db_schools(sch_id),
  constraint fk_pay_ter_id foreign key(ter_id) references db_terms(ter_id),
);

db_payments_subscription(
  pay_sus_id serial primary key,
  pay_id integer not null,
  peo_id integer not null,
  pay_sub_is_active boolean not null default true,
  constraint unique_pay_peo_value unique(pay_id, peo_id),
  constraint fk_pay_sus_pay_id foreign key(pay_id) references db_payments(pay_id),
  constraint fk_pay_sus_peo_id foreign key(peo_id) references db_people(peo_id)
);
```

Necesito una consulta en la que dado un pay_id, obtener todas las personas (estudiantes, admins, profesores) que no estén relacionadas en la tabla db_payments_subscriptions con ese pay_id, o que el pay_sub_is_active sea igual a false, considerando que pudieran haber personas que no se encuentran registradas en la tabla db_payments_subscriptions (también necesito esas personas), y que además, pertenezcan a un mismo db_terms o db_schools (ese valor se recibe de antemano).

el resultado debería de ser los peo_id que pertenecen a un colegio (ya sea como estudiante, admin o profesor) y que no están suscritos a un pago, o que en el caso de que exista el registro en la tabla de suscripciones, que el valor del campo pay_sub_is_active sea falso.

Esto es para una function en postgresql. La function recibe el pay_id, el sch_id y el ter_id.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from db_people peo
left join db_payments_subscription psub on psub.peo_id = peo.peo_id
where (psub.pay_id is null or psub.pay_id != 224 or (psub.pay_id = 224 and psub.pay_sub_is_active = false))
and (psub.peo_id in(
    select peo_id from eddu_students
    where ter_id = 2 and stu_status = 'IN PROGRESS'
    union
    select peo_id from db_admins adm
    join db_schools_admins sch_adm on sch_adm.adm_id = adm.adm_id
    where sch_adm.ter_id = 2
    union
    select peo_id from db_teachers tea
    join db_schools_teachers sch_tea on sch_tea.tea_id = tea.tea_id
    where sch_tea.ter_id = 2)
);
```

pero el problema de esa consulta es que solo me trae los peo_id que están registrados en la tabla db_payments_subscription, pero no los que no están registrado, está pasando por alto los que no están suscritos a ningún pago.